# vue :class binding for multiple styles in one

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

Simple question but I cannot find / figure it our by trying different syntax.
Working in vue and need to apply multiple styles (with tailwindcss). One style works nicely and below code validates but only the last style `text-red-300 for` show` is applied somehow.

```
:class="{ ['bg-green-500, text-xs, text-red-300']: show, 'ml-12': !show  }"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the array brackets and the commas:

```
:class="{
  'bg-green-500 text-xs text-red-300': show, 
  'ml-12': !show
}"
```

It is a regular JS object, the property string will be put into `class` verbatim if the value evaluates to something truthy

Comment: @Boq7 FWIW this is not a place for trial and error, this string is not JS syntax but is inserted as is to `class` attr. Since `bg-green-500,` is not a correct class name, `bg-green-500` style is not applied